# Codeigniter/PHP Titles won't update despite multiple updates to the code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been tasked with a small modification that is proving to be more frustrating then anticipated, let me explain:

I needed to change the "title=" of some icons on our website and despite having done that, it will not update. All titles are stored in a "index_lang.php" file and are called like so:

```
title='<?= $lang->line('freemodification') ?>'
```

The code in the "index_lang.php" file looks like this:

```
$lang["freemodification"]= "Modify this instruction freely.";
```

Despite me changing the description in this file to, for example:

```
$lang["freemodification"]= "Oh god help me please!";
```

It still keeps the previous description. I even searched the whole project for the old description but it appears nowhere in the code...

I tried changing things around to see where the problem could be coming from but it takes those changes into account.

Comment: use this title="<?= $lang->line('freemodification') ?>"

Comment: It didn't work... The code worked before, it understood the line with single quotations but it just won't take the new description into account for some odd reason! I even tried clearing the cache but to no avail.

Comment: So you have `$lang["freemodification"]` AND `$lang["modificationlibre"]` in that `index_lang.php` file? Did you change `title='<?= $lang->line('freemodification') ?>'` to `title='<?= $lang->line('modificationlibre') ?>'`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out kerbholz, some of the names were in French and I didn't translate that last one. Know that in my code, both names are indeed the same.

Comment: Could it be a cache problem?

Comment: are you using a cache? try keeping dev tools open with disable cache ticked. also this is weird syntax `$lang->line` thought it was `lang('some_key')` or `$this->lang->line('some_key')`

Comment: Yeah, I had the same reaction but it seems to works fine. As for the cache, tried disabling it via dev tools as suggested but no dice. I do not understand, for the life of me, how a description **that does not exist** in the code shows up on the website... The perks of resuming a two year old project that wasn't yours to begin with!

Comment: this is a longshot and probably way out of target... but could it be that you're forgetting to push changes into your live server or something similar? I know I've been there sometimes :)

Comment: Haha any help is appreciated! But no that's unfortunately not it, other elements update, it's really these specific icons that are giving me a hard time!

Comment: UPDATE: It doesn't seem to be a cache problem either, tried clearing it via Chrome, disabled it via dev tools as suggested and even tried manually with this line that I popped into the relevant controller:

    $this->output->delete_cache();